# Calling super's method (add namespace to Nokogiri XML document)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, xml-namespaces

I have an XML document which is missing some namespace declaration. I know I can define it when I use `doc.xpath()` method, like the following:

```
doc.xpath('//dc:title', 'dc' => 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/')
```

However I would like to add it once since I have a lot of xpath calls.

I found out that my `Nokogiri::XML::Document` is inherited from `Nokogiri::XML::Node`. And the Node class contains an `add_namespace()` method. However I can't call it, because it says it is undefined.

Is this because Ruby does not allow calling parent class's functions? Is there a way to go around this?

EDIT

I add the following console example:

```
> c = Nokogiri.XML(doc_text)
> c.class
 => Nokogiri::XML::Document
> c.add_namespace('a','b')
NoMethodError: undefined method `add_namespace' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x007fea4ee22c60>
```

And here is the [API document](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html) about Nokogiri::XML class

EDIT again:

The original doc was valid xml like this:

```
<root xmlns:ra="...">
  <item>
    <title/>
    <ra:price/>
  </item>
  <item>...
</root>
```

However there are too many items, and I have to create one object for each of these, serialize and save in the database. So for each object I took the item node and turn it into string and saved in the object.

Now after I revive the object from DB and I want to parse the item node again I came to this namespace issue.

Comment: maybe you want c.root.add_namespace('a','b')

Comment: So, to be clear you have an invalid XML document like `<root><foo:bar /></root>` and you want to define the `foo` namespace prior to or as a part of parsing? Could you provide a simple sample like the above and what you want to be able to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. While `Nokogiri::XML::Document` does inherit from `Nokogiri::XML::Node`, some methods are explicitly removed at the document level, including `add_namespace`

   https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb#L203
2. As @pguardiario notes, you want to add namespaces to the root element, not the document.
3. However, doing this after parsing the document is too late. Nokogiri has already created the nodes, discarding the namespaces:

   ```
   require 'nokogiri'
   xml = "<r><a:b/></r>"
   doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml)
   p doc.at('b').namespace
   #=> nil

   doc.root.add_namespace 'a', 'foo'
   puts doc
   #=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
   #=> <r xmlns:a="foo">
   #=>   <b/>
   #=> </r>
   ```

You'll need to fix your source XML as a string before parsing with Nokogiri. *(Unless there's some way with the SAX parser to add the namespace when you hit the first node, before moving on.)*